# Should I have a separate customer model and an address model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a simple eCommerce application.

I currently have a customer model and need to add a shipping address to this. Question is, should I create a new address model and associate this with my customer or put the address fields on my customer model? It seems like creating 2 models will be more effort as I will then need to update multiple models when my customers enter their details on the front end form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your customers will ever need to associate two addresses with their account then create two models.  Odds are they will.  Billing vs Shipping is the most common, but so is wanting to ship to home vs ship to work, etc.